# VirtualBox: Share whole Ubuntu drive on Windows (Host)

Tags: virtualbox, ruby, shared-folders

I currently have Ubuntu in VirtualBox.
Currently I do web development in the Ubuntu since its easier to run Ruby on Rails in Linux then its on windows.

But I had the idea to share the whole ubuntu drive with my Windows (Host).

So I can edit the files in Windows, and it gets updated in the Ubuntu.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use samba/cifs to share any directory and its subdirectory with Windows.

A problem you may encounter however is line endings in text files and codepages. Windows naturally moves to code page 1252 but Linux/Ubuntu will default to UTF8. Ensure all programs accessing the files can recognise and change the same codepage and line endings and it will work.

Comment: Can I make it so that the Samba share is only visible on my Host pc and not the whole network?

Comment: Yes. Look [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1173333).